# how to create SSIS package to feed values in a 'where in' clause

Tags: sql, ssis, package

am fairly new to SSIS ...
so here is my problem statement - I want to create a package that does the following..

1) to break a set a 1000 ID's(Primary Key) into sets of 100 ie 100*10
2) the 100 values got everytime must be dynamically fed into a variable-'X'
3) I want to use this variable in a where in clause

example : 
I have a table Students with 'ID' as the primary key 
I also have a table Rank_Holders with an 'ID' column 
select * from Rank_Holders where ID in (?)   is what I want to do .
? denotes the variable mapped -which should have the list of ID from Students.

Practically I have large databases here  one table from SQL Server and other from Oracle and the ID column is more than 30000 in number that is why I need to split it into chunks and feed in Where in clause

A step by step package creation process would really be helpful Please help with the same.

Comment: Your question is hard to follow, why do you want 100 values in a WHERE clause?  Is the set of 1000 that you want to break up coming from the 30,000 you mention below from two sources?

Comment: Bigger picture, you are attempting to create a divide and conquer strategy for pulling data from one system to another? When the package starts, a value of 1000 is supplied. Then the package will divvy that up into N buckets of work to perform that work in parallel?

Comment: hi guys , billinkc is right I want to have 1000 records split into n buckets , and each bucket's value is used to matchup with another data source.for for instance 1000 is split into 10 buckets bucktes 1-10 will run in a loop one after the another.

Comment: @Goat_co - that was an example given with 1000 records ...i wanted to make it clear that I have a more than 30000 values as where in has a limitation of 20000 entries. I decided to split the total values and split it to run in loops.

Comment: It just sounds like the wrong approach to much of anything to be looping through multiple subsets to feed WHERE criteria, but I don't feel like I understand your big picture well enough to contribute meaningfully.

Comment: actually there is no other option...this is the only way to go about it...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Newcommer! Realizing that you are pretty new to SSIS, I must tell that your problem statement while not ideal is pretty descriptive. It's very hard to describe the whole problem in a very few lines.

I am pretty sure you will be able to figure out the "step-by-step " part by yourself. I am trying to give you some general ideas.

1. The primary key may or may not be sequential. If it is, then you are in luck; if not, then you would need to use ROW_NUMBER(). Example:

DECLARE @lower int = 10;
DECLARE @upper int = 15;

--DECLARE @CETList varchar(3000); -- This I am putti

WITH subset AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RecordID) AS RowNumber , RecordID
    FROM #A 
)

--SELECT @CETList = COALESCE(@CETList + ',', '') + CAST(RecordID AS varchar)
--FROM subset 
--WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @lower AND @upper;

--SELECT @CETList;
--PRINT @CETList;

SELECT * From UserAudit where RecordID in (SELECT RecordID FROM subset WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @lower AND @upper );

Again, this is not yet a full solution. Please review and see if it can help you. I am putting this in the answer sections, because I need more space than what the comments section offers.